# How to overwrite existing symbol when linking?

Tags: c++, c, linker, greenhills

I am having two libs `A` and `B`. there having the same function `same_func`, I don't want to modify `A`'s code to remove `same_func` in `A` but override the symbol when linking. is there any way to indicate the
function in `B` lib having a higher priority to be chosen first if symbol conflicted.

Comment: If proper namespaces were used, the odds of this being an issue are reduced dramatically.

Comment: "I don't want to..." You should want less to create more hacks than cleaning up messy code.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the libraries on the command line commonly decides. Put library "B" before library "A".

If your application has a reference to `same_func()` and you set library "B" as the first one, the linker will resolve it to B's `same_func()`. Since the reference is resolved now, linking with library "A" will only resolve the references not yet resolved.

Answer (score 1):

A safer solution could be to make all or relevant symbols in libA as 'weak'. You can do this with objcopy using option --weaken. This would make sure that linker chooses definitions from libB if it's available in both A and B.
Another solution would be to make use of linker script to include or exclude specific sections from particular objects.